# Batch file for loop and searching sub directory

Tags: loops, batch-file, subdirectory

I am currently working on converting stl files to gcode files for my 3d printer.
I have them in folders based on types of prints they are (wall tiles, mini's, misc) and those have 1 or more folders in them.

I can convert the files if they are in the base folder but I want to keep them in their folders and move the files to copy of the folder structure when done so I don't duplicate the work.
I can get it to create the folders but when trying to `echo slicing "file"` it does nothing unless there is a file in the base folder.

*I looked at other questions and tried `for /d /r`.*

I left my code at home but the place I got the idea from is

```
echo off
for /d %%D in (c:\location\*) do (

    REM code to copy folders from start to done folder

    for %%F in (%%D\start\*.stl) do (
        echo slicing %%F
        move &&F %%D\done
    )
)
```

I have a robo copy that works before the second for loop starts.
I will edit this later tonight with the exact code I am currently using.

**EDIT:**

here is the code that I have that works so far:

```
echo off

for /d %%D in (G:\Slic3rbatch\profiles\*) do (

    REM copies each folder from start to done only

    robocopy %%D\start %%D\done /e /xf * >null
    echo Creating folders completed

    for /d %%F in (%%D\start\*) do (
        echo "Slicing : " %%F
    )
)

echo All files completed
REM PAUSE
```

Comment: `move &&F ..`?? Wasn't that `%%F`?

Comment: yeah that was me trying to type it from memory there.  in the first version of the code that had the basic function is %%